# M1 Money supply data?

Tags: money

Why do these M1 Money supply charts show data only up to 7th May, when the Fed data is released weekly?

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/M1

http://schrts.co/zgaAPi

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That’s what the source data goes up to at present: [Fed H.6](https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h6/current/default.htm)

The fact that it is weekly does not mean that it will be close to available in real time, they presumably need time to get the data for some components of the aggregate.